# Is it possible to run a TeamCity build with a VCS Root that is unavailable?

Tags: teamcity

My team has using TeamCity to automate some tiresome maintenance tasks, and over time, we've found we want to re-use common pieces, so we've got some common functions in a repository on Bitbucket.

For better or for worse, our Bitbucket has a daily backup/maintenance period that, when active, blocks all of our builds from running with the following error:

`Failed to collect changes` ... `Bitbucket is currently unavailable`

I've looked at the various checkout modes, though we're generally limited to checking out files on the server (Rather than agent). I had figured that if the files are checked out to the server, then if Bitbucket were unavailable, there would be some way to fall back on "Whatever is already there". Especially as we don't have `Clean build` checked.

Is there some way that we can fall back on whatever is already checked out on the TeamCity server? Or do we need to set up some kind of redundancy?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
you need to simply build a project in a directory location of a teamcity machine and then call the run from that location instead.

You can have a build with No VCS at all. This build run will utilize the folder you mentioned instead of cloning a VCS.